# Need assistance with aggregate Count function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have been doing nice little project to calculate the number of shipments per country made under particular office. I prefer to write a single query because otherwise it will take forever to process whole the data using while / for loops etc. 
For this reason I wrote a query as following:

```
   SELECT
COUNTRY.Code, COUNTRY.Name,
(SELECT COUNT(Shipment.Ref) FROM Shipment
LEFT JOIN Station  (NOLOCK) ON Station.STID = Shipment.STDEST
LEFT JOIN Country (NOLOCK) ON Station.Code = Country.Code
LEFT JOIN Client (NOLOCK) ON Client.CID = Shipment.CID
WHERE Client.CBUR = 'UKLON'
) AS NumOrder
FROM COUNTRY
```

And this return a total number of shipments and not per particular country

```
--------------------------------------
|Code    |Name              |NumOrder|
--------------------------------------
| BE     |BELGIUM           | 82460  |
| FR     |FRANCE            | 82460  |
| UK     |UNITED KINGDOM    | 82460  |
| NL     |NETHERLANDS       | 82460  |
| AZ     |AZERBAIJAN        | 82460  |
| HK     |HONG KONG         | 82460  |
| AU     |AUSTRALIA         | 82460  |
| RE     |REUNION ISLAND    | 82460  |
```

I really appreciate if anyone would give me a hint how to modify the existing query to be able to count those shipment per country based on the given office account .

Comment: How is office account stored?

Comment: what is TPAY.Code?

Comment: You definitely need to `GROUP BY`, but as I can't see the whole of your database, it's kinda not easy to say, by what field. Try to group, for instance, by country code.

Comment: It should by Tpay = Country. I did forget to change all the syntax of the query

Comment: I did not test all solutions you had given me but thanks for your great input into this query and sharing your knowledge!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the Country in the Count

```
SELECT
COUNTRY.Code, COUNTRY.Name,
(SELECT COUNT(Shipment.Ref) FROM Shipment
LEFT JOIN Station  (NOLOCK) ON Station.STID = Shipment.STDEST
LEFT JOIN Country (NOLOCK) ON Station.Code = TPAY.Code
LEFT JOIN Client (NOLOCK) ON Client.CID = Shipment.CID
WHERE Client.CBUR = 'UKLON' and Country.Name = C.Name --or this "and Country.Code = C.Code"
) AS NumOrder
FROM COUNTRY C
```

Comment: Thank you Aleksandar, your solution works absolutely perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
SELECT
    C.Code, C.Name,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(Shipment.Ref) FROM Shipment
        LEFT JOIN Station  (NOLOCK) ON Station.STID = Shipment.STDEST
        LEFT JOIN Client (NOLOCK) ON Client.CID = Shipment.CID
        WHERE Client.CBUR = 'UKLON' AND Station.Code=C.Code
    ) AS NumOrder
FROM COUNTRY C
```

**OR Use Group By:**

```
SELECT 
    C.Code, C.Name,
    COUNT(Shipment.Ref) AS NumOrder
FROM Shipment
LEFT JOIN Station  (NOLOCK) ON Station.STID = Shipment.STDEST
LEFT JOIN Client (NOLOCK) ON Client.CID = Shipment.CID
LEFT JOIN COUNTRY C ON Station.Code=C.Code
WHERE Client.CBUR = 'UKLON'
GROUP BY C.Code
```

Comment: The `GROUP BY` query would only get you countries for 'UKLON', however, and should also contain `C.Name,` in the `GROUP BY` clause for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Smth. like this, in one request, consider group by clause:

```
SELECT
COUNTRY.Code, COUNTRY.Name, COUNT(Shipment.Ref) 
FROM Country
-- joins go here: Shipment etc.
GROUP BY COUNTRY.Code, COUNTRY.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

These are my assumptions:

- STID is Station's primary key.
- CID is Client's primary key.
- TPAY is supposed to be Country.
- Code is Country's primary key.

So your left joins return one record anyway (the matching one or a dummy empty one). Outer joins make no sense in your query.

You are not correlating your subquery to your main query, i.e. you are not selecting records within for the country without. You'd have to add this to your WHERE clause in your subquery.

```
SELECT
  COUNTRY.Code, 
  COUNTRY.Name,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM Shipment
    JOIN Station ON Station.STID = Shipment.STDEST
    WHERE Station.Code = COUNTRY.Code
    AND Shipment.CID IN (SELECT CID FROM Client WHERE CBUR = 'UKLON')
  ) AS NumOrder
FROM COUNTRY;
```

And here is the same thing with the subquery in the FROM clause instead:

```
SELECT
  COUNTRY.Code, 
  COUNTRY.Name,
  counted.NumOrder
FROM COUNTRY
JOIN
(
  SELECT Station.Code, COUNT(*) AS NumOrder
  FROM Station 
  JOIN Shipment ON Shipment.STDEST = Station.STID
                AND Shipment.CID IN (SELECT CID FROM Client WHERE CBUR = 'UKLON')
  GROUP BY Station.Code
) counted ON counted.Code = COUNTRY.Code;
```